# 4 wires encoder to 6 wires Hibrid Servo drive for closed loop stepper motor

Tags: stepper-motor, encoder, closed-loop

I have the HBS860H driver and LPD3806.I wanna know if I can connect this 4 wire encoder, to this 6 wire driver.

HBS860H:
https://hardware-cnc.nl/images/PDF/ACT/HBS86H_English_Manuel.pdf

LPD3806: (i have the 600 impulse version)
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1422931/ORANGE/LPD3806-100BM-G5-24C/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but you need a converter like this one.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000448310517.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.78e03907adU9zV&algo_pvid=6e07528f-86bc-40bd-823b-b608260d6ff3&algo_exp_id=6e07528f-86bc-40bd-823b-b608260d6ff3-8

Choose the 24V to 5V 2 channel model

You can power your encoder and converter with 24VDC. On the connection from the converter to the HBS860H do this:

HBS  Converter
PB+ --> B+
PB- --> B-
PA+ --> A+
PA- --> A-
VCC --> Do not connect
GND --> GND

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!